# Expand content if sidebar isn't used

Tags: 7

I've been learning Drupal myself for over a year now. I've mainly used templates all the time and changed the `css`. This time I made my own template and put `php` in it for the first time. Everything worked but I was wondering how I can expand my content box if a sidebar isnt used? Oh, I'm using `Bootstrap's` css

Snippet of php:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar span4"><div class="section">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="content-area" class="span4">
          <?php print render($page['content']) ?>
        </div>


    <?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
      <div id="sidebar-second" class="column sidebar span4"><div class="section">
        <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
      </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-second -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

They all have `span4` but what I want is when sidebar 1 isn't used, then content id changes to `span8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be:

```
<div id="content-area" class="span<?php echo $page['sidebar_first'] ? '4' : '8'; ?>">
```